# The June 2016 archive.org archive seems to have crashed

Tags: discussion, status-completed, data-dump

https://archive.org/download/stackexchange/

While some of the archive files are very large, from the looks of it, it's been so long since electronics.stackexchange.com.7z was uploaded that it has crashed.

Or is archive.org just showing an out of date index of the archive?

Comment: Stack, please hire me as archivist and I will figure out how to make torrents that actually work reliably. It can be done! Without excessive ongoing expenses! (Except for my salary, which will surely dwarf all other costs.)

Comment: No repro: `electronics.stackexchange.com.7z                 22-Jun-2016 14:09     166.3M`

Comment: @ArtOfCode Looks like they restarted the whole archiving process, because they've all got today's dates.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is my fault - you caught things mid-upload (with a side of pausing) here. There were some nasty issues with backoffs due to improved speed of a new uploader script I wrote, which had weird side-effects as it retried.

The fun with archive.org is that *you don't know when to backoff*. It' a queue on their side which is processing stuff (e.g. a virus scan) and a limit of items in queue. It's not really related to any upload rate at all, but the processing speed they have *after* the upload. So I have to beef up our backoffs to compensate and re-kick the process a few times yesterday and I hit all the walls. But, we now have a much more resilient simple Linqpad upload script that transfers the dump in a single run. **Next run, there shouldn't be the same pauses (while I tweak code) where you see discrepancies during the process.**

Bonus fun fact: we learned that `WebClient.UploadFileTaskAsync` has a 2GB file limit when `AllowWriteStreamBuffering` is enabled, due to some `Int32`s under the covers in `HttpWebRequest`. Here's how to work around it:

```cs
private class StackWebClient : WebClient
 {
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var wr = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        ((HttpWebRequest)wr).AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
        return wr;
    }
 }
```

Comment: +1 for posting source code (also, I like that Meta.SE is now SO.)